# Python - turn some of the words in list/str to dots. len(list)?

Tags: python, string, list

I've started learning Python last week on codecademy and Google etc. but got stuck and couldn't find the answer anywhere so signed up on stackoverflow.com looking for your support.

I'm trying to build a program that only takes first 5 letters of any name and the remainder of the letter(s) to be shows as blank dot(s). e.g.

Adrian: "Adria."
Michael: "Micha.."
Alexander: "Alexa...." etc.

I tried to "fix" it with the "b" variable but that just prints three dots "..." regardless of how long the name is.

This is what I've got so far:

```
def namecheck():
  name = raw_input("Name?")
  if len(name) <=5:
    print name
  else:
    if len(name) >5:
      name = name[0:5]
      b = ("...")
      print name + b

namecheck()
```

I'm a total newbie so I apologise for any wrong spacing here, thank you for your support and patience.

Comment: Why would it print any other number of dots since you ask it to print exactly 3 dots? Just compute how many dots you need to print: `len(name)-5`.

Comment: `name[:5]+'.'*(len(name)-5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to sequence multiplication (one which is somewhat more self-documenting, and hopefully less confusing to maintainers), just [use `str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to do your padding:

```
def namecheck():
    name = raw_input("Name?")
    # Reduce to first five (or less) characters, then pad with .s to original length
    # with str.ljust
    print name[:5].ljust(len(name), '.')
```

`print name[:5] + '.' * (len(name) - 5)` works fine, it's just a bit arcane (and also involves more temporary values, though in practice, the lack of actual method calls makes it faster on CPython).

Answer (score 1):

The most concise way I can think of:

```
def namecheck():
  name = raw_input("Name?")
  print(name[0:5] + '.' * (len(name) - 5))

namecheck()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use the function replace().

```
name = 'abcdefg'
name.replace(name[5:], '.' * len(name[5:]))
output: 'abcde..'

name='randy12345'
name.replace(name[5:],'.' * len(name[5:]))
output: 'randy.....'
```

`name[5:]` means get all the element starting 6 (5+1 because it start with 0)

`'.' * len(name[5:]` then this code count it and multiply it by dot
`name.replace(name[5:],'.' * len(name[5:]))` then use replace function  to replace the excess element with dots

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
def namecheck():
  name = raw_input("Name?")
  if len(name) <= 5:
    print name
  else:
    print name[0:5] + '.' * (len(name)-5)

namecheck()
```

Comment: you don't even need the `if` / `else`.

Comment: Note: You could just unconditionally "pad" here. Don't check the length first, just unconditionally do `print name[:5] + '.' * (len(name) - 5)`. Python sequence multiplication treats a negative multiplier as equal to zero, so it behaves correctly without the explicit test.

Comment: @Julien, yes indeed